# Nuxt3 Handling Cookies in API Routes

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have global middleware:

```
import {useStore} from "~/store/useStore";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async () => {
    await useFetch('/api/setCookie')
    await useFetch('/api/getCookie')
});
```

And those two routes in `server/api/getCookie.ts` file:

```
import { getCookie } from "h3";

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {

    const cookie = getCookie(event, 'test_cookie')

    console.log('get cookie in Event Handler', cookie)

    return {
        hello: getCookie(event, 'test_cookie')
    }
})
```

and `server/api/setCookie.ts`:

```
import { setCookie } from "h3";

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {

    console.log('set cookie in Event Handler')
    setCookie(event, 'test_cookie', 'test_value')

    return {
        hello: 'world'
    }
})
```

When I run this app I expect to create cookie and `console.log` it but it doesn't save cookie even on multiple reloads of the app:

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I noticed on your sever API is that you did not set up what type of API route you are creating. In order to make the `setCookie` work, the file name of the route must be suffixed by `.post`.

If you want to make sure that the cookie will reach to your `getCookie` API route, [create a server middleware](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-middleware). e.g

Here are the working codes in refferrence to the example given

`~/server/middleware/get-cookie.ts`

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    event.context.custom_cookie = getCookie(event, 'my_cookie');
});
```

Set Cookie route
`~/server/api/set-cookie.post.ts`

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    try {
        setCookie(event, 'my_cookie', 'hello-my-cookie-12345', {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
            sameSite: 'none',
        });
        return 200
    } catch (error) {
        return createError({
            statusCode: 500,
            statusMessage: 'Something went wrong.',
        })
    }
});
```

Get Cookie route `~/server/api/get-cookie.ts`

```js
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    try {
        console.log('Cookie is', event.context.custom_cookie)
        return 200
    } catch (error) {
        return createError({ statusCode: 500, statusMessage: 'Something went wrong.' })
    }
})
```

The `event.context.custom_cookie` is from the server middleware.

In your directory middleware
`~/middleware/cookie.ts`

```js
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async () => {
    await useFetch('/api/set-cookie', { method: 'POST' })
    await useFetch('/api/get-cookie')
});
```

Define the middleware in your page.

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
definePageMeta({
    middleware: 'cookie',
});
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        Hello World
    </div>
</template>
<style scoped lang="css"></style>
```

Tested and it works
[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wAQWt1CdafE

Comment: Can you share repo with working example? For me it doesn't work I recreated your exact setup https://github.com/d0peCode/nuxt3-pinia-middleware-issue/tree/set-cookie-from-route-middleware and I have log `Cookie is undefined`

Comment: Here is the repo. I updated the middleware, instead of `useFetch` I use `$fetch`. 
https://github.com/ReaganM02/Set-Cookie-SSR-Example

Here is the live example deployed on Vercel
https://set-cookie-ssr-example.vercel.app/

Comment: Your example works because route middleware which you created - `auth.ts` executes both from server and the client side. If you change your auth.ts middleware to be global and executed only on server side then the cookie is never set. Can you give me permissions to write in this repo? I'll make a branch to show you what I mean. My gh username is `d0peCode`

Comment: Just add `if (process.client) {return}` at the top of your `defineNuxtRouteMiddleware` callback function. Make sure to manually delete the cookie before you start testing. With above line the cookie is never set.

Comment: I just added you on the repo. Sorry I don't clearly understand what you mean. My understanding with the codes given are for testing purposes only on how to set and get cookies. Can you share us what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have nuxt plugin in which I globally handle 401 response from my backend (something like http interceptor). If in plugin I receive 401 I refresh access token and I want to create new / overwrite httpOnly flagged cookies. That's why I need to set cookies from server side in plugin/middleware.

Comment: I pushed to repo

Comment: I think it might be impossible to set cookie from server side of route middleware / nuxt plugin because it's happening in same ssr cycle, page is loading and in route middleware it's about to show up and suddenly we execute nitro endpoint which suppose to create cookie after headers are actually already sent.. :(

Comment: On the refresh access token, you meant more like a refresh token? If so, I've done this something like this on my previous app. I am using a short live refresh token and every time a user refreshes the page,  the access token automatically renew and verify if it is valid. I got the idea from this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4TtAGhr61VI